# How can 10V AC change to 12V DC?

Tags: ac, dc, converter, adapter

[image: 12V]

This is a circuit that takes 220V DC as an input. I understand how the 220V AC changed to 10V AC and changed to DC by whole-wave rectifier. But why is it 12V??

Comment: It'll be more like 12.7 volts.

Comment: note that if you pull the max current of the transformer, that voltage will drop to 10v or even lower.

Answer (score 4):

1VAC has 1.414 times the peak value, so 10 VAC has about 14 volts peak, so the capacitor will charge to about 14V DC, slightly less due to diode dropping some voltage. Depending on the load, it can be approximated to be unregulated 12V DC.

Answer (score 0):

Converting AC to DC follows an RMS equation.  Which for a **sine wave** simplifies to

\$DC=1.414*AC\$

Putting numbers into that:

\$1.414*10 = 14.14V\$ open circuit.
When current is flowing continuously (through the LED and/or the load), the forward diode drops of \$0.7V\$ each will subtract \$1.4V\$ and get you to \$12.6V\$